# Changing the color of text once the button is clicked in C#..?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code where i am trying to change the color of the text after button click but nothings happening

My color function is ambiguous because i am using `itextsharp` and `system.drawing` library...

I tried using the below code..though its not giving error but color of the text is not changing..i tried using `clickedbutton`. `Forecolor`  function as well but it still remains the same.. both the functions are not working

```
btn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

clickedbutton.Forecolor= System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

I want to change the color of the text present under

```
ClickedButton.Text="Input Processing"
```

Any inputs will be highly appreciated.i know its a very silly question but i am confused :(

My code is

```
private void btn_Preprocess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    clickedButton.Text = "Input Processing...";
    btn_Preprocess.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    clickedButton.Enabled = false;

    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        SourcePath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    string searchPattern = "*.*";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(SourcePath);

    GetFiles1(di, searchPattern);

    MessageBox.Show("Process Complete");
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand. You want to change the button with text "Input Processing" that is clickedButton but your code change the color of  btn_Preprocess...

Comment: Are you sure it's asp.net and not WinForms?

Comment: It's WinForm because of in WPF is Foreground the property instead of ForeColor

Comment: its windows form..

LPs-- bro i tried using clickedbutton.forecolor=System.Drawing.Color.Red;

but its not working ...

i even removed the disabling property but nothing changes...

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are trying to change the forecolor of a disabled button. You can use EnabledChanged event to set the forecolor of a disabled button.

```
private void Button1_EnabledChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
         Button1.ForeColor = Button1.enabled == false ? System.Drawing.Color.Red :System.Drawing.Color.Black;

    }
```

Comment: even if i am removing the clicked.button=true function ...the color of the text is not changing ...and its not giving ny error ....

Comment: i tried your suggestion but its not working out

Comment: I found a similar question and checked the answer. It works. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18717410/2736255

Answer (score 0):

A disabled button will use a different color than the one set on ForeColor.
If you try not disabling the button clickedButton.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red should work.

Comment: i tried it bro but nothings working ....that is a reason i had to ask this question ...