# Is there an alternative to using the Paint Event to change Disabled ForeColor of a button?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, text-rendering, paintevent

I ran into an issue of buttons in my current project "not looking disabled enough", based on some feedback. Some people did not immediately recognize some buttons were disabled. This is primarily because the font color didn't change to a light enough color to be noticeable (I'm not sure how the color is automatically figured when disabling, but that's besides the point). Here's what it was looking like:

[image]

So this is what lead me to create a module Extension that allows me to `.Enable` or `.Disable` any button easily and control the `.ForeColor`. So it ended up looking like this:

[image]

I got the idea of how to handle the formatting changes like this from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717090/how-to-avoid-color-changes-when-button-is-disabled), but there were some comments (and I've learned from my own experience) that it's best not to mess with the Paint event (I'll talk about that more and illustrate below.)

**ERGO MY QUESTION:**

**Is there a reasonable alternative to using the Paint event to control the formatting of a button?**

Here are a few guiding points:

1. I don't want to make a whole custom control, just so I can have some minor color changes --my extension is much simpler and can be applied to any button.
2. I'm looking for something simpler than using the paint event and is less likely to cause issues in other implementations.
3. One core reason I want to avoid anything to do with the Paint event is you have to "Back up" your text to another variable so you can clear the `.Text` so it doesn't render on the button in addition to your custom rendering, but after rendering you cannot reassign the `.Text` in the Paint event because that raises the event over again causing an infinite loop, which means from that point out, you have to leave the button's `.Text` empty.

**HERE'S THE CODE:**

(with excessive comments in the Paint event to explain the reasoning behind the way I'm handling things)

```vb
Module Extensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Sub Enable(ByVal btn As Button)
        If btn.Tag = Nothing Then ' << This ensures we only add the handler once.
            AddHandler btn.EnabledChanged, AddressOf btn_EnabledChanged
            AddHandler btn.Paint, AddressOf btn_Paint
        End If
        btn.Enabled = True
        btn.ForeColor = Color.MidnightBlue
    End Sub

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Sub Disable(ByVal btn As Button)
        If btn.Tag = Nothing Then ' << This ensures we only add the handler once.
            AddHandler btn.EnabledChanged, AddressOf btn_EnabledChanged
            AddHandler btn.Paint, AddressOf btn_Paint
        End If
        btn.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_EnabledChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        If sender.enabled = False Then
            btn.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
        Else
            btn.ForeColor = Color.MidnightBlue
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        'Dim TextForBtn As String = ""  ' << we don't use a variable because that would only be useful if we could reassign to the .Text property, but that just raises the Paint Event again causing a infinite loop.
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        If btn.Text > " " Then
            btn.Tag = btn.Text ' << this allows us to redraw the text, the one issue however is the .Text property is empty from here on out.
            'TextForBtn = btn.Text ' << this is part of the failed idea of using a variable and reassigning to the .Text property.
        End If
        btn.Text = String.Empty ' << make sure Text is not written on button as well as rendered below
        Dim flags As TextFormatFlags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter Or TextFormatFlags.WordBreak  'center the text
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, btn.Tag.ToString, btn.Font, e.ClipRectangle, btn.ForeColor, flags) ' << TextForBtn was replaced with btn.Tag.ToString in the second parameter
        'btn.Text = TextForBtn ' << this is what caused an infinite loop necessitating the use of the .Tag property.
    End Sub
End Module
```

**FINAL NOTE:**

I am open to any tips on how to optimize the code I have to address my concerns, but I'm fairly convinced that the only way certain issues can be addressed is if there were a way to do the same trick without having to touch Paint.

Comment: Have you thought about using a Graphics (colored) object instead of text (to define the Button function)? When the Button is disabled, the Image will be unmistakably grayed-out (no other actions needed).

Comment: Be aware that custom colour selection may render your application inaccessible (i.e. breaking accessibility standards). And interfere with accessibility tools (like Windows Narrator).